# Divide column based on characters while consolidating information in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with repeated observations and a single column with unique observations. I'd like to consolidate this so that the columns with repeated information are single rows wherein the column with unique values is converted into multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#create sample dataframe
df_1 <- data.frame(v_1=c('x', 'x','x', 'y', 'y'),
    v_2= c('s','s','s','t','t'),
    v_3=c('a','b','c','d','e'))
df_1

#split v_3 into multiple columns
df_2 <- df_1 %>% separate(v_3, unique(df$v_3))
df_2 #here I am receiving an error message "'into' must be a character vector, not 'NULL'"

###Target Output###

  v_1  v_2  v_3_1  v_3_2  v_3_3
1  x    s     a       b     c  
2  y    t     d       e     NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# paste all v_3 values together by v_1 and v_2 to a temp column V1
ans <- setDT(df_1)[, toString(v_3), by = .(v_1, v_2)]
# split the just collapsed values to new columns
ans[, paste0("v_3_", seq.int(length(tstrsplit(ans$V1, ", ")))) := tstrsplit(V1, ", ")]
# remove the temp-column V1
ans[, V1 := NULL][]
#    v_1 v_2 v_3_1 v_3_2 v_3_3
# 1:   x   s     a     b     c
# 2:   y   t     d     e  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
library(purrr) # map, reduce
map(names(df_1)[-1],
  function(nm)
    group_by(df_1, v_1) %>%
      reframe(v = unique(!!sym(nm)), n = seq_along(v)) %>%
      pivot_wider(id_cols = v_1, names_from = "n", values_from = "v", names_prefix = paste0(nm, "_"))
) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "v_1")
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
#   v_1   v_2_1 v_3_1 v_3_2 v_3_3
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 x     s     a     b     c    
# 2 y     t     d     e     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_1                                                                   |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -v_1)                                            |>
  unique()                                                             |>
  mutate(v = paste(name, row_number(), sep = "_"), .by = c(v_1, name)) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = v_1, names_from = v, values_from = value)

#   v_1   v_2_1 v_3_1 v_3_2 v_3_3
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 x     s     a     b     c    
# 2 y     t     d     e     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```r
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% group_by(v_1) %>% mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = row,values_from = v_3, names_prefix = 'v_3_')

# output

# A tibble: 2 × 5
# Groups:   v_1 [2]
  v_1   v_2   v_3_1 v_3_2 v_3_3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x     s     a     b     c    
2 y     t     d     e     <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please select an answer whichever has worked well for you.